# Angular file upload is aborting upload process while route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-file-upload

In our project we have a  requirement like , while user is navigating across the pages (route change) we need to retain upload process behind the scenes . But as scope is getting destroyed while navigation , upload process is automatically getting aborted . is there any way to retain the upload process ??

I tried to deep clone the files obj array and keeping the process in service , but while cloning I am getting rangeerror when the maximum call stack sizeexceeded
Please do help ??

Comment: services are running on a different layer, as far as I know. Try moving your entire logic into a service/factory

Comment: Please post your code along with the issue. Moving your logic to a service layer will preserve the data during navigation (though not during refresh, which destroys client side variables) and is a better way to share data across the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my issue. Saved lot of time . Along with moving the logic into service layer I have cloned files object and maintained the que to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UI-Router - the way I got around that was to put the upload container in the nav, which is omnipresent.  So when you upload a file, and navigate to other routes, the upload is not interrupted.

So if you create a view on the template that never changes down the state tree, your app can upload while you navigate to other routes.

```
<div ui-view="nav"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

Inside the nav view - you can add a controller where you manage the upload, or add a component (upload)  Something like the nav/menu stays stagnant across the app, so you should be able to successfully upload multiple files at a time (parallel).